# Python - get file path programmatically?

Tags: python, windows, path, os.system

I am trying to create a Python program that uses the os.system() function to create a new process (application) based on user input... However, this only works when the user inputs "notepad.exe". It does not work, for instance, when a user inputs "firefox.exe". I know this is a path issue because the error says that the file does not exist. I assume then that Windows has some default path setup for notepad that does allow notepad to run when I ask it to? So this leads to my question: is there any way to programmatically find the path to any application a user inputs, assuming it does in fact exist? I find it hard to believe the only way to open a file is by defining the entire path at some point. Or maybe there's a way that Windows does this for me that I do not know how to access? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You could always try locating the file, but what happens when the user has several `.exe` files with the same name?

Comment: I can return that fact and ask for further specification I guess. But is that the accepted way of approaching this?

Comment: It's the same on all operating systems, generally. Linux is designed to look in certain folders if you type just an executable name, like `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. Windows does the same, except programs you install generally aren't put into one of these default path folders. You're better off defining the full path than searching the entire file system for the file.

Comment: On windows you can use the registry although that isn't full proof, you could also deploy your program with a database of common installation paths, yet another option would be to create an algorithm with os.walk to go throught the program files directory and make a list of exe's. You might also consider some functionality to handle different versions of the same program. Then use this information to provide the user with different versions and programs to launch. I suspect you are trying to make something like [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the location of the files in the PATH environment variable. Follow the steps: Go to My Computer->Right click->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Click Environmental Variables. Now click PATH and then click EDIT. In the variable value field, go to the end and append ';' (without quotes) and then add the absolute path of the .exe file which you want to run via your program.